# splitting html tag data to multiple coluumn

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Actually I am stuck at a issue, my data is in the format given in below image,

[Splitting data to multiple column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7PIQ1.png)

Is there any way in python dataframe to segregate this data to multiple column example,

[Data in required format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qN5aM.png)

Can anyone help me out.

I have tried to split it but it does not work,

```
df3=df.technische_daten.str.split('\s+(?=\<\/[a-z]+\>)', expand=True)
df3[0]=df3[0].str.replace(r'<li>', '', regex=False)
df3[1]=df3[1].str.replace(r'</li> ','',regex=True)
```

Data Snippet:
`<ul><li>Höhe: 248 mm</li><li>Länge: 297 mm</li><li>Breite: 246 mm</li><li>Gewicht: 4,0 kg</li><li>Leerlaufdrehzahl: 5500 U/min</li><li>Sägeblattdurchmesser: 190 mm</li><li>Leistungsaufnahme: 1400 Watt</li><li>Standard: 821552-6,B-02939,195837-9,164095-8</li><li>Bohrung: 30 mm</li><li>Schnittleistung 45°: 48,5 mm</li><li>Vibration Sägen Holz: 2,5 m/s²</li><li>Schnittleistung 0°: 67 mm</li><li>Sägeblatt-Ø / Bohrung: 190/30 mm</li><li>Max. Schnitttiefe 90°: 67 mm</li><li>Schnittleistung 0°/45°: 67/48,5 mm</li></ul>`

Comment: Hi, could you maybe add a smaller snippet of the data source so that users can test it by themselves? Generally speaking, posting images is not recommended as they are hard to use. Also, as you seem to have already loaded the data into a dataframe (but with in 1 column), can you also add how you did that?

Comment: Load data was in csv file so I loaded the data from a csv file to dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

Helpfully it's a built in function of pandas, which will make a HTML table for you.

```
import pandas as pd

df_rows = []

# put the below in a for loop to get all of your rows
# rows = all_your_data
# for row in rows:
# remove this line and use the above for loop
row = "<ul><li>Höhe: 248 mm</li><li>Länge: 297 mm</li><li>Breite: 246 mm</li><li>Gewicht: 4,0 kg</li><li>Leerlaufdrehzahl: 5500 U/min</li><li>Sägeblattdurchmesser: 190 mm</li><li>Leistungsaufnahme: 1400 Watt</li><li>Standard: 821552-6,B-02939,195837-9,164095-8</li><li>Bohrung: 30 mm</li><li>Schnittleistung 45°: 48,5 mm</li><li>Vibration Sägen Holz: 2,5 m/s²</li><li>Schnittleistung 0°: 67 mm</li><li>Sägeblatt-Ø / Bohrung: 190/30 mm</li><li>Max. Schnitttiefe 90°: 67 mm</li><li>Schnittleistung 0°/45°: 67/48,5 mm</li></ul>"
values = row.split("</li><li>")
# clean the data
values[0] = values[0].replace("<ul><li>", "")
values[-1] = values[-1].replace("</li></ul>", "")
dict_of_values = {}
for value in values:
    dict_of_values[value.split(": ")[0]] = value.split(": ")[1]
    
df_rows.append(dict_of_values)


# outside of for loop
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(df_rows, orient='columns')
# use df.drop to remove any columns you do not need
df = df.drop(['Leerlaufdrehzahl', 'Sägeblattdurchmesser'], axis=1)

your_html = df.to_html()
```

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: This does not solves my problem. I need a individual column but this just changes to html.

Comment: Please provide your data source, are you saying a single column in your dataframe contains multiple values? If this is the case, then your data should be cleaned before it is passed into the dataframe so the above method can be used.

Comment: I have added a data snippet in the question, this is just one row I want this data in tags to appear in different column for this single column